# Applying Screen Restriction by Installing App from Google Play

Tags: android, screen, resolution

I have developed an app in which I want such a functionality that If the Screen size is below 3 Inch then the app should not be installed from Google play.

So what do I have to do for the same.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add `<support-screens>` in your `manifest.xml`

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Go to [Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) for more information..

Comment: What to do if I want to restrict user to run on local machine on which I have developed that app?

Comment: Means the app is in pipeline. Now I want that if the local machine/handset's screen size is below  inch then the app should not be installed on that device. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: @DhrupadBhatt just set `<support-screens>` attributes as per your Requirement.... go to my link for the demo...